# Store ID on selecting the value in auto suggest

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I need to store a id of the selected value in another text box, here id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28' -auto suggest text box and id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T29' is dummy text box, while selecting the value in the auto suggest text box it should store the id  of the selected value in dummy text box. here is my code

```
var company = [];    
$().SPServices({ 
    operation: "GetListItems", 
    listName: "company",
    CAMLViewFields: "",
    CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Inactive'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
    async: false, 
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
    company.push({label:$(this).attr("ows_Title"),value:$(this).attr("ows_ID")}); 
    }); 
    } 
    }); 



    $("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28']").autocomplete({ 
    source: company, 
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui) {

    alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.value) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    $("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T29']").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
            },


    focus: function(event, ui){

    $("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28']").val(ui.item.label); 
    $("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T29']").val(ui.item.label);


              return false;
            }
    });
```

In above code it all works , my problem is at once the value selected in auto suggest text box , it displays the id in dummy text box and the id gets hide in dummy text box, i don't what mistake i have done...

Comment: can u create the fiddle?

Comment: i have created the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ygr/ -@MilindAnantwar

Comment: Can you hardcode the xml in it.

Comment: I cant able to hardcore the xml, i am working in server -@MilindAnantwar

Comment: I have attached the xml as image as you have asked, can you please check this - @MilindAnantwar

Comment: It is not clear. i would suggest you to set above xml as variable and then use it in fiddle.

Comment: I have set the variable in fiddle you can check that now -@MilindAnantwar

Comment: There are errors in console.please check the,